# How can I import and use labels from one Stata file to the current?

Tags: stata

I have file `aa` with a variable `x` which is labeled with value label `x_lab`. I would like to use this value label on the variable `x` of Stata file `bb`:

```
use bb, clear
label value x x_lab
```

How can I import the value label `x_lab`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `label save`, which saves value labels in a do-file:

```
label save x_lab using label.do
use bb, clear
do label.do
```

See [Stata help for label](http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?label).

Answer (score 1):

This answer technique didn't work for me as I wanted the variable labels created with e.g. `label var connected "connected household"`, not the value labels.

Instead I used this advice: http://statalist.1588530.n2.nabble.com/st-How-to-export-variables-window-td3937733.html

```
************* 
sysuse auto, clear 

log using mylog, name(newlog) replace 

foreach var of varlist _all{ 
 di _col(3) "`var'" _col(20) "`:var label `var''" 
} 

log close newlog 

//translate from proprietary format
translate mylog.smcl mylog.txt, replace 
!start mylog.txt 
*************
```

To fix the labels that extended over multiple lines so they just used a single one, I then replaced the `\n      >` for the oversized labels with nothing (in regex mode in atom). I could easily save into TSV from there.

Specifically:

- Clean up header and footer text in the logfile output.
- On Mac: use "\n" instead of "\r\n".
- On Windows: first "\r\n      -> ""
- then whitespace at beginning "\r\n        " --> "\r\n"
- then convert whitespace with 3 or more spaces in middle to tabs "  +" --> "\t"
- (Edit manually additional errors on tab if there are still some left)
- save as mylog.tsv
- open in Excel, and use table of labels as needed.